# What is the purpose of "proxy_set_header REMOTE-HOST $remote_addr"?

Tags: wordpress, nginx, http-headers, reverse-proxy

I am learning to add a reverse proxy for WordPress, and in the process of referring to other people's configuration parameters, I found that someone used the following parameters in the configuration.

```
proxy_set_header REMOTE-HOST $remote_addr;
```

I tried to search the web to understand it, but I couldn't find any information about it. What exactly does it do, please?

Comment: This seems to be a non-standard way of achieving the same result as an `X-Forwarded-For` header. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61092127/whats-the-purpose-of-setting-x-forwarded-for-header-in-nginx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its purpose: It tells the reverse proxy software (nginx) to add an HTTP header to each request it forwards from your audiences' browsers to your server. The header it adds looks something like this:

```
REMOTE-HOST: 198.51.100.121
```

This header announces to your server the IP address of your audience. Without it your WordPress web server logs would show all requests coming from the proxy server's address. Which is boring and useless.

But you're doing it strangely. You should be using [the `X-Forwarded-For` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Forwarded-For).  The nginx directive for that is

```
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

and in the HTTP request it looks something like this

```
X-Forwarded-For: 198.51.100.121
```

There's probably no harm in adding your `REMOTE-HOST` header, but the standard is X-Forwarded-For.